# Can I implement timeout on VB6?

Tags: vb6, timeout

I wanted to know if there is an implement of timeout on VB6.

I have some function Do(), Can I call this method with timeout?

something like:

```
Call(Do, 5);
```

that will quit after 5 seconds.

Do() function is not my it so I can't change it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to create a background worker, implement a sleep (5000) then terminate the background process. You can take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Do note that your simplistic answer hides a lot of complexity. There is no `BackgroundWorker` component in VB 6; that only exists in VB.NET. The only way to get at it in VB 6 is to create a COM wrapper for the VB.NET `BackgroundWorker` control and consume it from a VB 6 app.

Comment: hi @CodyGray , check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109(v=vs.71).aspx : Using Background Threads with Visual Basic 6

Comment: Yes, you had the same link in your answer. I already looked at it, and I quite well understand what it says. Read my comment again. I didn't say it wasn't *possible*, I said it was quite a bit more difficult than your answer makes it sound.

Comment: Of course it is quite complicated, every implementation of multithreading in an application is complex, but it is the way to do what Dor Cohen requested.

Comment: Hiya, agree with @codygray how about using settimer and killtimer apihttp://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=235938 , hope this helps, I can help you to find an example, cheers

Comment: Hi @Tats_innit, can a function get a hook to settimer ?

Comment: Hiya there @XabierArrabal, cheers for reply, nope but I was thinking setting a timer and invoking killtimer after certain seconds? and let the third party api reside in between; what do you think; hmmm something like this : http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/windows/240783/240783/callback-for-settimer-function/ **OR** http://www.internetcomputerforum.com/visual-basic-forum/278529-invoke-sub-arguments-settimer-callback-function.html callback on timeproc cheers

Comment: Yep, i understand, but the fact is.. how would the function be stopped then? lets get into account that he does not have access to the function itself and it is not a shell process (he could use WaitForSingleObject then, but this is not the case). The only way that i can think of to accomplish this is to wrap the function into a background worker, then he can use a sleep or even do a 5 seconds loop (adding doevents not to block the application) and then kill the background worker, i do not see any other solution .. :-S

Comment: @XabierArrabal Actually, yeah - in any case this requires thread clean up in the end. but good to discuss with you; (better than force kill the callback). cheers!

Comment: With this approach, you also have to be careful about global variables. Global variables in VB6 are not really global: they are per-thread (each thread has its own private copy of all global variables). Also, the VB6 runtime is not initialized on a new thread until you create at least one VB6 object on the thread, so you might want to create a "dummy" object to make sure the runtime is initialized properly on the thread.